# Hard fork vs onchain-governance for Tezos

Tags: xtz, governance, hardfork

What are the main pros and cons of implementing protocol changes on Tezos via hard-forking vs onchain-governance?

Comment: I am not sure if *self*-governance is the appropriate term here. I think I understand what you mean but presumably you mean *onchain*-governance ?

Comment: Yep, you're right, edited my post

Comment: Interesting question but not a good fit for this venue. The goal is to have a good resource for developers looking for information on Tezos.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a link where Arthur B. talks about the need for hard forks:

https://medium.com/tezos/there-is-no-need-for-hard-forks-86b68165e67d

The summary is that new features should be done via on chain governance as they can be contentious and we want to avoid centralization. On chain governance empowers stakeholders to vote on whether they want those changes. But since blockchains are still software and software may have potential issues that requires hotfixing, hard forks are exercised to avoid crippling of the network.